# progress view for multiple image downloads

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, download, sdwebimage

Here's my scenario: I have two UIImageViews stack together (one on top of the other), something like below:

[image]

I want to make them visible to user only when both of them finished loading image (I am using [SDWebImage with Progress View](https://github.com/kevinrenskers/SDWebImage-ProgressView) library). Before that, I need to hide both ImageView and show a progress indicator.

I want to have **one progress indicator to indicate both of the two image downloading progress**, but not sure how to do it.

Please share some thoughts on the approach of doing this.. Thanks!

Comment: If you know the progress of each... why not `(progress1 / 2) + (progress2 / 2)`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Here is my solution:

```
    var progressArray = [CGFloat]()
    for url in urlArray {
        progressArray.append(0.0)
        var index = templateArray.indexOfObject(url)
        SDWebImageDownloader.sharedDownloader().downloadImageWithURL(url, options: nil, progress: { (receivedSize:Int, expectedSize:Int) -> Void in
            let currentProgress:CGFloat = CGFloat(receivedSize) / CGFloat(expectedSize)
            progressArray[index] = currentProgress
            var totalProgress:CGFloat = 0.0
            for progress in progressArray {
                totalProgress += progress / CGFloat(templateArray.count)
            }
            self.progressView.setProgress(Float(totalProgress), animated: true)
        }, completed: { (image, imageData, error, finished) -> Void in
            // Download complete.
            if (self.progressView.progress == 1) {
            }
        })
```

hope this can help someone.